# How to calculate the Gibbs free energy out of a given Entropy?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

I'm stuck in a small calculation. I try to solve a small exercise.

You should calculate for a given entropy the Gibbs free energy, where the entropy is given as

$S\left(U,V\right) = \frac{4}{3}\left(\alpha V U^3\right)^{1/4} \qquad\dots\qquad U$ is the internal energy, $V$ is the volume and $\alpha > 0, \text{const}$

The exercise say something like "you get a surprisingly expression for the Gibbs free energy".

---

Basically I have to use the definition of the Gibbs free energy:

$$
\begin{equation}
G\left(T,p\right) = U\left(S,V\right) - T\cdot S + p \cdot V
\label{eqn:gibbs}
\end{equation}
$$

The question is now, how can we exchange the volume $V$ and the entropy $S$ in the equation above. My idea was to calculate $p=p\left(T,V\right)$ and transpose it to $V=V\left(p,T\right)$. The thing is, that I get for the pressure $p$ something like:
$p = \frac{\alpha}{3}T^4$, which is not $p = p\left(T,V\right)$ and it's not possible to find a relation for $V=V\left(p,T\right)$. I thing, I'm making some mistake. Can someone help me?

Comment: [Have you tried](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermodynamic_equations) $\frac{p}{T}=\frac{∂S}{∂V}$? Also why is it not possible to find a relation for $V$ if $S$ and $V$ are algebraically related?

Comment: Honestly there is no need to change to natural variables if they are asking only for "Gibbs free energy".

Comment: What do you mean with there is no need for the change of the natural variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may also use $T=\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial S}\right)_V=\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial U}\right)_V^{-1}$.

Comment: Okay. You will get $T = \left(\frac{U}{V\alpha}\right)^{1/4}$. I already got this. I was interested to calculate the equation of state between internal energy $U$, temperature $T$ and volume $V$. You will get $U\left(T,V\right)=\alpha V T^4$.

Comment: From the formula I gave you get $T=\frac{4}{3}\frac{U}{S}$, you also have $p=T\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial V}\right)_U=T\frac{1}{4}\frac{S}{V}$. What else do you need to get the Gibbs free energy?

Comment: Aha. Okay. Now I got it. At the end I will get $G = 0$. That's what I thought I should get. I was kind of blind and didn't saw that I can put everything together.

Answer (score 1):

Let me add a more general solution to this question.
The proposed fundamental equation for the entropy $S(U,V)$ is a homogeneous function of degree 1 of its variables (extensiveness of the entropy). As a consequence also the fundamental equation $U(S,V)$, obtained from the original fundamental equation is a homogeneous function of degree 1. Therefore, as a consequence of Euler's theorem:
$$
U=\left(\frac{\partial{U}}{\partial{S}}\right)_VS+\left(\frac{\partial{U}}{\partial{V}}\right)_SV=TS-pV
$$

The definition of $G$ as double Legendre transform of $U(S,V)$ with respect to its variables implies
$$
G=U-TS+pV
$$

and combining the two expressions, we get the general result that
$$
G=0
$$
as soon $U$ (or $S$) is a homogeneous function of ($S,V$) ( or ($U,V$)).

Let's notice that the same "zero" thermodynamic potential is obtained every time one evaluates the  Legendre transform of the internal energy with respect to *all* its extensive variables.